Understanding Entity Roles and Admissible Values in Wikidata Triples via SPARQL
I am currently working with Wikidata and utilizing SPARQL queries to extract information. I'm interested in understanding the roles of entities within triples and the admissible values for certain properties.

Is it possible for an entity, such as http://www.wikidata.org/entity/q241665 (Rachel Stevens), to be both the subject and object of a triple? If not, is there a method or API available to determine whether an entity can act as a subject or object?
Furthermore, regarding Wikidata properties like http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/p569 (date of birth), is there a way to ascertain the admissible values that can be used as subjects or objects?

I'm also curious if there exists documentation provided by Wikidata that explicitly outlines when an entity can serve as a subject or object within a triple. Any insights or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.


yes, why not? I mean, you have to think of the knowledge graph as a graph connecting entities to other entities and entities to literals (e.g. dates, numbers etc.). And that graph is indeed a directed graph, somebody has to decide the direction of the relations in the data model. E.g. there might be a relation "has birth place" which links a person to a place, others might create such a relation some other knowledge graph as "is birth place of", which then would link a place to a person.


You'll almost always find edges in the graph that link to the entity, and other edges which are outgoing edges starting from the entity. Otherwise it would be hard to create a meaningful knowledge graph. You can always check for outgoing edges (the entity would be the subject) and incoming edges (the entity would be the object) by using a query language, e.g. here SPARQL


Wikidata has some kind of constraints defined to the properties, if you check your example scroll down. There are definitions of "subjects types" and ranges - those are indicators of possible types of entities in subject/object position and literal types in object position.


that's by the way what I mentioned with passing this in the prompt to the LLM. Or as I also mentioned in the other thread, for the entity retrieval pre-processing step, using those domain/range type constraints to query for possible entity candidates matching the named entities of the question and filter by the intended types. Then pass those entity candidates with type to the LLM in the prompt.

@UninformedUser I see what you mean. Concerning question 2 you told me that it’s possible to get those information such as subjects types and ranges in the web page but is there a sort of API/get requests to retrieve those information ? Otherwise the only solution I see is to scrape the web page. I am intentioned to use that information in the prompt such that the model is aware of the subject and object entities.
